# How to check equivalence using Fluent Assertion Should().BeEquivalentTo() when using derived classes

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I'm having problems trying to get Should().BeEquivalentTo() to work with types that derive from a base class and implement a collection interface:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Derived : Entity, ICollection<Entity>
{
    private List<Entity> m_Children = new List<Entity>();

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Count => ((ICollection<Entity>)m_Children).Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => ((ICollection<Entity>)m_Children).IsReadOnly;

    public void Add(Entity item)
    {
        ((ICollection<Entity>)m_Children).Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        ((ICollection<Entity>)m_Children).Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(Entity item)
    {
        return ((ICollection<Entity>)m_Children).Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(Entity[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        ((ICollection<Entity>)m_Children).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Entity> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((ICollection<Entity>)m_Children).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Remove(Entity item)
    {
        return ((ICollection<Entity>)m_Children).Remove(item);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((ICollection<Entity>)m_Children).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The Test

```
[TestMethod]
public void EquivalenceTest()
{
    var expected = new Derived
    {
        Id = "123",
        Name = "abc",
        Description = "def"
    };
    var actual = new Derived
    {
        Id = "121",
        Name = "xyz",
        Description = "def"
    };    

    actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);   // This succeeds, but should fail
}
```

The call to BeEquivalentTo seems to be ignoring the properties that are defined in the object, and only treating the object as a collection.

How can I get the framework to check the properties and the contents of the collection?

**Edit**
It seems like this is [a known issue](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/860)

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Where is `actualChild` defined?

Comment: Apologies - cut and paste error. I've now edited the original post.

Comment: Something's still not right - `Derived` has a typo in the declaration (colon but no base type).

Comment: It seems that this is a known issue - I've added a link. But does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/860) when comparing classes that implements `IEnumerable` and have extra properties to be compared.

Here's *a* way to hack the comparison.

```cs
public class Entity : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private int[] ints = new[] { 1 };

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<int>)ints).GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<int>)ints).GetEnumerator();
}

[TestMethod]
public void EquivalenceTest()
{
    var expected = new Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "abc",
    };

    var actual = new Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "abc",
    };

    actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, opt => opt
        .Using<Entity>(e =>
            e.Subject.Should().Match<Entity>(f => f.Name == e.Expectation.Name)
            .And.Subject.Should().Match<Entity>(f => f.Id == e.Expectation.Id)
                .And.Subject.Should().BeEquivalentTo(e.Expectation)
        )
        .WhenTypeIs<Entity>());
}
```

Comment: Is there any way of implementing this 'hack' more generically, so it inspects the public properties of the class rather than having to code each property manually?

Comment: It seems that you don't ened to compare each property. Just using actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, opt => opt
                .Using<Entity>(e => e.Subject.Should().BeEquivalentTo(e.Expectation))
                .WhenTypeIs<Entity>()); works.